# Android Set TextView Width for long text

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView in which text is dynamically assigned to the textview.

I am scrolling the textview in the horizontal direction (from right to left).
I am doing the scrolling by setting the X coordinate of the TextView.

My problem is,
for long text that exceeds the screen width(LCD width), the textview only shows the text that is in the range of a single line and next it creates a new line for the rest of the text.

But, I want the text to retain to one line only and let it scroll horizontally on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the textview breaking on the screen width was using Relative Layout.

I changed the Relative Layout to Linear Layout with setting the layout width to 5000dp, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

set singleLine and scrollHorizontally to true on the XML layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

setting the X coordinate doesn't work because the TextView is being built with the width of the LCD, you're not really scrolling the text, just moving the view.

Answer (score 0):

Set property

`android:singleLine="true"`

for textview

Answer (score 0):

you can set property of Padding from Right side and along with this set the width of the TextView  or Select Single line property

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

may this help you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this , you just need to write. .

android:singleLine="true"

this will allow you to write huge amount of data in a EditText with in proper range.